# Document Information Panel Validation Issue in Office 365 Word Desktop Client

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, term-store, sharepoint-library, term

I have created a document libray in SharePoint 2013 named as 'DIP' and I have added one required field named 'Type of Document' and this  is a custom site column with data type Managed metadata. There is setting in termstore where we can mark whether certain termstore availble for tagging or not in new documents or existing documents.('Available for Tagging' ). I have un-checked for certain term value (Example : stale term value'Handbok' in below snapshot)
[image]

Expectation here is when an existing document using the stale term then word client should stop user from saving document and it shouldn't allowing user to check-in the document unless stale term value is changed.

**With Word 2013 Client:**
It's working perfectly fine with Word 2013 desktop client where user will get the below validation error message (as shown in below screenshot) if they are trying to save document with stale term value and it will allow user to save only after changing the stale term value to other value.
[image]

**Word Office 365 Client**
In word office 365 version, User were able to save and check-in  the document even if the stale term value there in the existing document(refer below screenshot from word 365 with stale term value). The validation pop which is shown in word 2013 is not shown to user with word 365 version and this is something missing in word 365.  s
[image]

Can anyone share your suggestion why I am not getting that validation pop with word 365 version or any other workaround would be helpful.Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/document-information-panel-deprecate), the reason why it doesn’t work in office 365 may be the Document Information Panel (DIP) is deprecated in Office 2016 applications.

Comment: No, I'm not using Office 2016 application and I understand that it has been deprecated in office 2016 application but not M365 applications. I have M365 Word installed on my machine.

Comment: Thanks Casey. Issue still persist with M365. Can anyone suggest an alternate solution for this issue